# Kubernete CreateContainerConfigError

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to deploy an app on k8s but I keep getting the following error

```
NAME                READY   STATUS                       RESTARTS   AGE
pod_name            1/2     CreateContainerConfigError   0          26m
```

If I try to see what went wrong using `kubectl describe pod pod_name` I get the following error: `Error from server (NotFound): pods "pod_name" not found`

Comment: Share the yaml to check further.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include the command that generated the output shown, so it's hard to tell.  Perhaps you're looking at different namespaces?

Answer (score 1):

One of the parameters key in the file was misspelling making the deploy fail. Unfortunately, the error message was not helpful...

Answer (score 0):

CreateContainerConfigError means kubernetes is unable to find the configmap you have provided for volume.
Make sure both pod and configmap are deployed in same namespace.
Do cross verify the name of configmap you have created and configmap name you have specified in pod volume definition is same.

Answer (score 0):

the message `Error from server (NotFound): pods "pod_name" not found` is very clear for me that you deployed your pod in a different namespace

In your deployment yaml file check the value of `namespace` and execute the command

`kubectl describe pod pod_name -n namespace_from_yaml_file`